# Where is the .Fill Method

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm using this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

Why there's no [.Fill method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)?

> 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Fill' and
>   no extension method 'Fill' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?

I would like to use like

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Fill();
```

Comment: Where's your data adapter? I see an `adapter` variable, but no declaration of a `DataAdapter`.

Comment: thank you guys.. I really thought that `DataTable` has `.Fill` method. I think I have something's error in my eyes now. By the way, all the answer have +1 from me. again thank you.

Comment: Best is that you mark one answer as the solution, so this is clear to people who come and see this question. :)

Comment: yes. so I choose Mr. Tim Schmelter for a having more upvotes. cheers. thank you @Abbas.. im not seriously developing using this `DataTable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DataTable` cannot fill itself. You need a `DataAdapter` therefore.

For example with [`DbDataAdapter.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are looking for [`DataAdapter.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/607k6dd0.aspx).

> Adds or refreshes rows in the DataSet to match those in the data source.

`DataTable` doesn't have a `Fill` method.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the DataAdapter class: [**MSDN: DataAdapter Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx).

==> [DataAdapter.Fill Method (DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For fill data you have to use DataAdapter class.

nad for fill data to datatable or dataset use syntax as below.

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter= new SqlDataAdapter();

adapter.Fill(dt);
```

For dataset

```
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

If you are using OleDb for fill data hv to use

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter= new OleDbDataAdapter();
```

Comment: you're too late.. anyway welcome to stackOveflow! and you have a +1 `:D`